# Enabling Disabling Text Fields using PHP when a radio button is clicked

Tags: javascript, php, html, user-interface

I have 2 radio buttons(Enable/Disable) and 3 text boxes. I want to disable the 3 textboxes if disable radio button is clicked.

```
<Input type = 'Radio' Name ='target' value= 'r1'>Enable 
<Input type = 'Radio' Name ='target' value= 'r2'>Disable 
T1: <input type="text" name="t1"> 
T2: <input type="text" name="t2"> 
T3: <input type="text" name="t3">
```

This change should happen as soon as I select one of the radio button. I am using PHP. TIA!

Comment: you should use jquery for this

Comment: Can you tell me the exact command? I am a beginner when it comes to this. Found different commands on the net and it confused me more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comments Here is the code. use jquery code with other text box. make sure you should include jquery library at the top of the code

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $("#enable").click(function() {
      $("#t1").attr("disabled", false);
    });

   $("#disable").click(function() {
      $("#t1").attr("disabled", true);
    });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<Input type = 'Radio' Name ='target' value= 'r1' id="enable">Enable 
<Input type = 'Radio' Name ='target' value= 'r2' id="disable">Disable 
T1: <input type="text" name="t1" id="t1"> 

  
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @GYaN i have apply only 1 text box and i have mention that try this code with other textbox. also i remove other 2 textboxes

Comment: @GYaN oooohh sorry. i have fixed. thanks for your correction

Answer (score 1):

Although, using jQuery will make it easier, the following is one way to do it purely in JavaScript:

```js
let textboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=text]');

document.querySelectorAll('input[name=target]')
  .forEach(function(radio) {
    radio.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
      let value = e.target.value;

      if (value === 'r1') {
        textboxes
          .forEach(function(textbox) {
            textbox.disabled = false;
          });
      } else if (value === 'r2') {
        textboxes
          .forEach(function(textbox) {
            textbox.disabled = true;
          });
      }
    });
  });
```

```html
<Input type='Radio' Name='target' value='r1'>Enable
<Input type='Radio' Name='target' value='r2'>Disable
<br><br>

T1: <input type="text" name="t1">
T2: <input type="text" name="t2">
T3: <input type="text" name="t3">
```

It basically listens for the `change` event of the radio buttons and the loops through the text boxes to enable/disable them.

Answer (score 1):

```js
 $('.radio').click(function(e) {
        var val = $(this).val();
      if(val=="r2") $('input[type="text"]').attr('disabled','disabled'); 
      else  $('input[type="text"]').removeAttr('disabled');
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label><Input class="radio" type = 'Radio' checked Name ='target' value= 'r1'>Enable </label>
<label><Input class="radio" type = 'Radio' Name ='target' value= 'r2'>Disable </label><br /><br />
T1: <input type="text" name="t1"> 
T2: <input type="text" name="t2"> 
T3: <input type="text" name="t3">
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, as you are using PHP, which is a server-side language, whenever you click `radiobutton,` refresh the page, and the `radiobutton` will get back to the unchecked state. So for this, you have to use JavaScript, and jquery is the best way to work with DOM elements. You need to add a few more lines of code. Don't forget to add jQuery in your HTML's ` tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#enable").click(function () {
            $("#t1").attr("disabled", true);
        });

        $("#disable").click(function () {
            $("#t1").attr("disabled", false);
        });
    });
</script>
```